# how to use mongodbexport in python or shell script

Tags: python, mongodb

i want to create a json output from mongodb by mongodbexport

it act correctly in terminal by this command :

```
sudo mongoexport --db mydb --collection url_db --query '{"state": "processed"}' --out /mongodb_json/name.JSON
```

but how can i use it in a shell script or in a python by subprocess.call

i use this code in python :

```
call(["mongoexport", "--db","mydb","--collection","url_db","--query","'{\"state\": \"processed\"}'","--out ",outfile],shell=True)
```

but it create this error: "no collection specified!" ,"Export MongoDB data to CSV, TSV or JSON files."

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are passing your arguments in via a `list`, you need to remove the `shell = True` argument, otherwise only the first element of the list is used to construct your subprocess call (in this case only `mongoexport` is called)

```
call(["mongoexport", "--db","mydb","--collection","url_db","--query","'{\"state\": \"processed\"}'","--out ",outfile])
```

You only use `shell = True` when you're passing your command as a `string` not a `list`

```
call("mongoexport --db mydb --collection url_db --query '{\"state\": \"processed\"}' --out " + outfile, shell=True)
```